# sql - Only want rows with NULL in column if it isn't defined somewhere else as well

Tags: sql

I have a table with possible NULL values in a column.  I need to return the NULL values, but only if it isn't also defined somewhere else.  Below, I want row F, but I do not want row B.  We have some automation that attempts something but also has a fail over.  We need to identify when both tries fail.

```
Column 1 | Column 2
A        |        1
B        |        1
B        |     null
C        |        2
C        |        1
D        |        1
E        |        2
F        |     null
F        |     null
G        |        2
```

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result!

Answer (score 1):

Simply do aggregation :

```
select col1, null as col2
from table t
group by col1
having max(col2) is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.column1 = t.column1 and t1.column2 is not null
)
```

Or you can use window functions:

```
select column1, column2
from (
    select t.*, max(column2) over(partition by column1) max_column2
    from mytable t
) t
where max_column2 is null
```